# Neo4j cypher query: how to add dynamic alias in neo4j cyper query

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to have dynamic alias for field in neo4j cypher query

Some thing like

```
MATCH (n:instance) -- (d:instance) RETURN d.value as d.field
```

where the d is having a the following data

```
    {
        field: "username",
        value: 1
     }
```

so as to get the result as

```
{username: 2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is no possible. Cypher currently only supports the creation of properties with static (i.e., hardcoded) names, even in dynamically-generated maps.

As a possible workaround, you could return a 2-element array instead of a map. This query:

```
MATCH (n:instance) -- (d:instance)
RETURN [d.field, d.value];
```

would produce a result that looks like:

```
["username", 2]
```